# Sitecore Relative Multilist

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

In Sitecore I have a folder called Models, a folder called Products and a folder called Years under my home item. In Models I have a a list of products. Models has a multilist that points to the Years item as it's data source. Products has a multilist which points to Models as a data source. I need to also give Products a multipicker that points to Years however these dates can only be dates that are available for it's selected Models. I need something that can pretty much look at the multilist of items chosen by a multilist as a datasource. I'm not sure if this is something possible out of the box. The reason I want to do this rather than nesting these three folders is to avoid duplicating content but I'm not sure if I can get around this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a way out of the box. But I can think of a way where you could extend the Multilist and add it as custom field. Then override the source property and manipulate the value on set.

Here is an example where this is done to allow relative queries:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Custom%20TreeList%20that%20supports%20query.aspx

You would need to be aware of the selected models by getting the values from the corresponding field (using ItemID property to load the current item) and once you have that you could set the source to the years root folder and use data source parameters to exclude the ones you don't need.

Here is a good post about what options you have on the data source: 
http://getfishtank.ca/blog/treelist-data-source-hidden-functionality

Downside of this is that you need to save the item before the custom tree is aware of the selected models. Another downside is that you might have to validate selected years because if you make changes in the selected models then the selected years could be invalid.

Comment: Also take a look at [Using A Field For A Data Source](http://getfishtank.ca/blog/using-item-field-as-a-data-source-in-sitecore). Again, you need to save the item first.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is an out of box option for having cascading fields similar to what you described. You may need a custom field. Here is the full documentation on how to create a custom field in Sitecore
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Creating%20a%20Composite%20Custom%20Field.aspx